# How to make plain input for hours:minutes?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm struggling to create a very plain user input field that allows the user to only enter hours:minutes in this format: "00:00". The idea is to be only text input, no date pickers, calendars, clocks, AM/PM, etc.

I dont know if i should be looking at regex, since i want the user input to be in the format specified above, and be validated on input.

I've tried using `input type="time"` but it behaves differently across platforms and browsers (adds AM/PM in Firefox, displays a clock picker on Android, etc.) i've tried something like

`<v-text-field oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}|20|21|22|23):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1});"></v-text-field>`, but i couldn't get it to work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `mask` to format input text field value right.
For Vue.js there is simple yet powerful mask component - https://vuejs-tips.github.io/vue-the-mask/

So, you should:

1. Install component with
   `npm i -S vue-the-mask`
2. Import it i.e. locally inside the component

```
import {TheMask} from 'vue-the-mask'
export default {
  components: {TheMask}
}
```

3. Use it with appropriate mask

```
<the-mask :mask="['##:##']" />
```

Codesandbox link with `##:##` example - https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-dijkstra-np411

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I'll give it a shot :)
P.S. I dont think the sandbox is working, i'm only seeing the default Vue homepage.

Comment: I think I forgot to save it. Please check again.